# How to override one function in multiple commands?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

We are in the process of migrating an old application to Laravel. The old application manages different projects and has an "admin" database for the main application and creates a new database for each project. We would prefer to keep this structure but it creates some problems for things such as migrations.

Initially we created our own base command that implements the `handle()` function so that any command that extends this command will loop through all the project databases. This means we have changed the structure so that migrations are separated into two directories since we have "admin" and "project" migrations for the different types of databases. We also duplicate each Laravel command that is already there if it doesn't work with our implementation out of the box.

However this creates a lot of duplicate code as we made our own implementation of the migrate command that simply passes calls to Laravels own migrate command. I now find myself having to implement the `--force` option into our new command for example.

So what I would like to do is override the `handle()` function in all the Laravel console commands in some way. **Is there a better way of implementing this?**

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own base class for your artisan classes and extends your commands from it.

Comment: On your base class you can override the handle method and call its parent before/after your customization

Comment: Can I improve my question to make it clearer that I would prefer to modify the existing Laravel commands and not create our own commands? We are currently doing this and it creates a lot of duplicate code

Comment: Good point, maybe I am overthinking this. I guess it is possible that project databases would have their own queue, sessions and passport credentials but this has not been implemented yet.